# Looking for a Parameter chosing IF Statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I've figured out a function to do this, but now I ran into this problem, I need to parsename the user entered parameter, users will enter something like 11234#Elgin,address1,Address2      I need to take out the numbers and # from the first parameter so that I am left with just Elgin, my function looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.JohnnyAddress1 (@office varchar(max), @home varchar(max), @school varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
as begin
declare @return varchar(max)

set @return = case @office
when 'Elgin' then @home
when 'Simcoe' then @school
when 'Grey Bruce' then @home
when 'Toronto School' then @school
when 'Muskoka School' then @school
when '' then ''

end
Return @return
end
```

I was thinking something like :

```
declare @parsed varchar(max)
parsename(replace(@office,'#','.'),2) as @parsed
```

But I am quite clueless as to the syntax and also how to use this @parsed in my case.

Comment: You will have to have the address type of 'Elgin' or 'Simcoe' in the record to pass. Plus varchar(max) seems like over kill for a 6 digit field, why not reduce it to a varchar(50)?

Comment: Ok i've got the function and it seems to work but I have one more weird issue, I need to parse out the parameter that the user enters, so they will enter something like  Exec Function(1111#Elgin,Adress1,Address2)
I need to split up 1111#Elgin and turn it to  just  Elgin, there will always be a # then the name, and I need to change this parameter for the function to work:

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which flavor of SQL you are using.  This is for T-SQL.

```
Select Right('1234#Elgin',Len('1234#Elgin')-Charindex('#','1234#Elgin',0))
```

Select the Right portion of the string starting from the location of the '#'.

Answer (score 0):

> Function(1111#Elgin,Adress1,Address2) I need to split up 1111#Elgin
>   and turn it to just Elgin, there will always be a # then the name, and
>   I need to change this parameter for the function to work:

I see this as everything to the right of `#` and left of `,` or

```
SET @X = RIGHT(@INPUT,Charindex('#',@INPUT))
SET @Y = LEFT(@X, CHARINDEX(',',@X))

SELECT @Y
```